# How to get offset status and other metadata information when working with KStream in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, offset, status, apache-kafka-streams

Situation:

The class `KafkaConsumer` has some nice methods like: `partitionFor`, `begginingOffsets` and `endOffsets` also `commited` and `position`.

All those methods are helpful, when assessing e.g. load situation in the topic.

When working with streams - `KStream`, how to get offset status and other metadata infromation?

How to check in runtime within Java code stream status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, the only way to access the properties you describe (well, a subset of those properties, anyway) with the DSL is using `#transform()` and or `#process()`. These are basically Processor API methods, so you can access the `ProcessorContext`, which gives you access to topic, partition, offset, and timestamp. Otherwise you can't access these properties with the DSL.

There's no way at all to access partitionFor, begginingOffsets, endOffsets, committed, or position in Kafka Streams. These are completely hidden.

Comment: I wish they would add a way to get at least the timestamp using the DSL, although I am not aware of any plan to do so :(

Comment: KIP-159 :) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-159%3A+Introducing+Rich+functions+to+Streams

Comment: Awesome. Why are these called "rich" functions? Doesn't seem to be explained anywhere and I seem to be lacking some context.

Comment: In the proposal KIP-159: Introducing Rich functions to Streams there are not all methods regarding e.g. offsets. There is only `offset()` method in `RecordContext`, but in the `KafkaConsumer` there are more important methods.

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki maybe drop a note about this on the mailing list? That's where KIP discussion takes place. My guess is they want to abstract those other methods, but I think they might be useful even in Streams context.

Comment: The KIP is not finalized -- the name is "Rich" is borrowed from another system -- and yes, please give feedback on the mailing list! The idea is to give access to all meta data that record context offers. Offset, partition, topic, timestamp. (Maybe even headers...)